# Overview_path in DirectionsRoute in google Maps for javaScript equivalant in Direction Api of google Maps for Java

Tags: java, google-maps

i want to get the array of LatLngs that represent an approximate (smoothed) path of the resulting directions in java using google maps api. this array is reterned in directionsRoute of google maps for javascript, i am unable to find its equivalant in java?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`decodePath()`](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.2.6/javadoc/com/google/maps/model/EncodedPolyline.html#decodePath--) method in the [`EncodedPolyline`](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.2.6/javadoc/com/google/maps/model/EncodedPolyline.html) field of the [`DirectionsRoute`](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.2.6/javadoc/com/google/maps/model/DirectionsRoute.html) object to get a list of the coordinates. Here's some small sample code:

```
DirectionsRoute[] routes = DirectionsResult.routes;
EncodedPolyline polyline = routes[0].overviewPolyline;
List<LatLng> overviewPath = polyline.decodePath();
```